# Why is [dos] sometimes in the output of a save in "vim". such as: "foo.txt [dos] 38L, 193C"?

Tags: command-line, file, vi

In certain text files, after doing a save in `vim` with `:w`, the output mentions `[dos]` as such:
`"foo.txt" [dos] 38L, 193C`

Why is `[dos]` displayed?

As a simple test, I've created a new file with `vim` on a `FAT32` disk attached to my Mac. Those files don't display `[dos]` after a save in `vim`. I copied that file to `/tmp` (native MacOS format). Opening it there does not display `[dos]` upon a save in `vim` either.

So, `foo.txt` has Japanese characters. A portion looks like:

> 臣
>   区
>   ...
>   草
>   早
>   古
>   谷
>   "foo.txt" [dos] 38L, 193C

some testing:

> /tmp$ file -I foo.txt
>   foo.txt: text/plain; charset=**utf-8**

`foo.txt` life cycle:

1. On *XP* I created lots of text files using *TextEdit* that had Japanese characters and saved to *FAT32* file system (usb drive).
2. They were archived into a `ZIP` format.
3. That usb drive was attached and copied to my MacBook (*MacOS Extended / Journaled*).
4. `/usr/bin/unzip` unarchived them, and here I am.

Text files are such a basic cross-platform file format. Obviously, "something" is different with those `[dos]` marked files... What flags a file as being a `[dos]` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What flags a file as being a [dos] file?

Line endings. Windows uses CR (carrage return) and NL (newline) characters. Old Mac plain text files use CR and macOS (and other Unix like systems) command line editors use NL.

Comment: facepalm. ah yes, the good old "CR" / "NL" scourge. ":set ff=unix" and ":set ff=dos" lets for toggling. thanks!